# How do I set document defaults in a Notebook?

Tags: r

I have a notebook in R studio and want to avoid setting Echo = FALSE for every chunk of code individually.

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
````

I can't for the life of me find the global document settings.

The syntax

```
opts_chunk$set(include = FALSE)
```

Provided [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) doesn't work for me.

Is there a way to do this in the setup block?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

I just figured it out - needed to simply reference the knitr library. Was assuming this would be accessible in the notebook.

Then the code:

```
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

works